# How do I display a graph in Laravel which uses two different values from the same database table?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make a laravel application where a line graph displays the blood sugar levels of the logged in user which corresponds to a particular day. I'm using ConsoleTV package at the moment but open to other options.

I've tried a couple of different queries but I can't seem to get it to show exactly what I want. On the Y-axis rather than showing the blood sugar level it just counts the number of recordings for that day.

My Controller:

```
public function chart()
{
   // $bloodSugar = BloodSugar::where(\DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%D'))"),date('D'))->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();

    $bloodSugar = BloodSugar::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();


    $chart = Charts::database($bloodSugar, 'line', 'highcharts')
        ->title('Blood Sugars')
        ->elementLabel('Blood Sugar Level')
        ->groupByDay();

    return view ('bloodsugars.index', compact('chart'));
}
```

My User Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(BloodSugar::class);
    }
}
```

My Blood Sugar Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BloodSugar extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['date', 'time', 'blood_sugar_level', 'scenario', 'user_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

My User Database Table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->date('dob')->nullable();
            $table->string('diabetic_type')->nullable();
            $table->string('other_info')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('provider')->nullable();
            $table->string('provider_id')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

My Blood Sugar Table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateBloodSugarsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('blood_sugars', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->date('date');
            $table->time('time');
            $table->double('blood_sugar_level');
            $table->text('scenario');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('blood_sugars');
    }
}
```

My graph currently outputs the count of the number of blood sugars recorded for that day - rather than the actual blood sugar level itself.

Comment: Please, show your DB structure or model.

Comment: I checked the documentation and the source for ConsoleTV and don't see `Charts`. Where is this class coming from?

Comment: @Tarasovych Added DB structure and Model for you.

Comment: @MichaelCordingley I think I'm using a slightly older version as I used this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KrAvrU2XYuY&t=2370s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to help when you're using a version of the library that's out of date and doesn't match the current documentation. The best that I can do is to point you to a solution given the current documentation.

Check out the [Eloquent example](https://charts.erik.cat/adding_datasets.html#database-eloquent-example), as that's what I'm modifying to give you these examples. These would slot into the middle of your controller method. Below, we simply give a line chart of readings at each time of day.

```
$chart = new SampleChart;

$chart->labels($bloodSugar->map(function (Bloodsugar $reading) {
    return Carbon::parse($reading->date . ' ' . $reading->time);
}));

$chart->dataset('Bloodsugar Readings', 'line', $bloodSugar->pluck('blood_sugar_level'));
```

If you want to report the average blood sugar by day, then you just transform the data a bit using `Collection` methods before passing it off to the charting library:

```
// Keys are dates and values are average levels for those dates.
$averageBloodSugarByDay = $bloodSugar->groupBy('date')
    ->map(function (Bloodsugar $readingsForDate) {
        return $readingsForDate->avg('blood_sugar_level');
    });

$chart = new SampleChart;

$chart->labels($averageBloodSugarByDay->keys());
$chart->dataset('Bloodsugar Readings', 'line', $averageBloodSugarByDay->values());
```

Refer to the [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods) documentation if you're unclear about anything going on in these snippets.

Comment: This worked after a bit of tweaking - Just changed $data to $bloodSugar instead and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Oops. Updated my answer to fix that error in the code. You're welcome!